# Why paint Kohanim in ram's blood?

Tags: kohen-priest, symbols-symbology, blood, tetzaveh

In parshas Tetzaveh [29:20](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0229.htm#20) the Torah explains the details about painting different parts of the Kohen in ram's blood.  I get the whole idea of the symbolism of the different parts of the body (according to R' Hirsch), but it does strike me as odd (and perhaps a little icky) to use ram's blood (rather than eg olive oil).  Has anyone seen an explanation for that?