Becoming a cohen and purification of metzorah
What is the connection of the procedure described in the inauguration of cohanim to that of the purification of metzorah? Both have oil and blood applied at the same three places: right ear, right thumb, and right big toe.
Kohen: Shemos 29:20, Vayikra 8:23-24.
Metzorah: Vayikra 14: 17, 25, 28.

close question https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/35203/why-paint-kohanim-in-rams-blood
